# django - i18n - create translation but use it later?

Tags: python, django, django-rosetta

I want to use a string which is not in use yet. so there is no any `{% trans 'word_I_want_to_use' %}` in template nor in views/models yet.

can I just create it like this in views.py?

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
_("word_I_want_to_use")
```

and `makemessages` and `compilemessages`.

and later on, I will put the `{% trans 'word_I_want_to_use' %}` in template.

will this work?

Comment: Yes this will. You goal is to make it available for translation while not using it anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. That will work. You can also use [lazy translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#lazy-translation), so that you have no performance impact for the unused translation:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
_("word_I_want_to_use")
```

Alternatively, you can use [`ugettext_noop`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#marking-strings-as-no-op) for only translating but never directly using the string. This depends on you plans and use case.